# how to convert a vector to closure color in OSL

Tags: shaders, osl

I am trying to implement the Cook-Torrance function in OSL.
The Cook-Torrance function is:
[image]

where D(h,alpha) is a function which returns a float as well as G(v,l,alpha).
F(v,h,f0) returns a vector.
How do I convert the output vector to closure color ?
I tried something like this:
BRDF = color(out) * emission();
But I am not sure if it's correct to multiply color * emission().